# Best way to run background task in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, background-process, intentservice

After doing some research on what is the best way to run a background task from an Android Activity in a way that it persists throughout all the Activity changes (e.g. rotations) I've come up with two possible solutions, yet still have not decided which one is the best.

The solution you first find is by using IntentService, that way the process is run in a segregated thread and does not mess with the main ui thread.

The other solution to persist the task is to run it in a Fragment class without a graphic interface.

I'm looking forward to being able to handle any type of Object as a result of the background task. I've read that the IntentService can only handle intents in that way and all the objects that takes need to be Serializable/Parcelable. So that is kind of a limitation IMHO.

Comment: Use intentService thats the best way for you.. if you task will completed then automatically it release its thread

Comment: it actually depends on what you want to do. Loaders can be used as well

Comment: "I've read that the IntentService can only handle intents in that way and all the objects that takes need to be Serializable/Parcelable. So that is kind of a limitation IMHO." -- `IntentService` receives *input* in the form of an `Intent`. It has no built-in concept of "a result of the background task". I would recommend using greenrobot's EventBus to post an event when the work is complete.